# Inserting parentheses at random place?

Tags: string, random, insert, equation

stackoverflow community! I am once again asking for your help...

I have made a random equation generator that generates a string like this:

```
def strmaker():
    picker = random.randint(2, 5)
    if picker == 5:
        return "1" + random.choice(RandomSymbols) + "2" + random.choice(RandomSymbols) + "3" + random.choice(
            RandomSymbols) + "4" + random.choice(RandomSymbols) + "5"
    elif picker == 4:
        return "1" + random.choice(RandomSymbols) + "2" + random.choice(RandomSymbols) + "3" + random.choice(
            RandomSymbols) + "4"
    elif picker == 3:
        return "1" + random.choice(RandomSymbols) + "2" + random.choice(RandomSymbols) + "3"
    else: return "1" + random.choice(RandomSymbols) + "2"
```

The typical outcome of this would look like this:

```
1-2*3-4
```

So basically what i wanna do is:
Make some code/function that inserts one or multiple sets of parentheses
at a random spot.

Like this!

```
(1-2)*3-4
```

Or this!

```
(1-2)*(3-4)
```

Or...

```
(1-2*3)-4
```

I think you get it at this point.
What would be the simplest way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The laziest way to do this is, of course, to just add more cases, where each case corresponds to a particular arrangement of opening and closing parens.  For example, we might add the cases:

```py
elif picker == 6:
  return "(1" + random.choice(RandomSymbols) + "2)"
```

However, I think we can do better than that, particularly given the constraint that this program enforces where each number is only one digit long (if we wanted to generalize to code with more digits, it would be a bit of fiddling, but shouldn't be too bad I think).  What this constraint means is that, if we are to insert an opening parenthesis, we need to insert a closing parenthesis exactly 3, 5, 7, ... characters away.  In particular, then, we could write code that looks something like:

```py
s = strmaker()
i = 0
while i < len(s) - 2:  # len(s) - 2 since we never want a starting paren on the last number
  if random.randint(0, 1): # 50% chance of opening paren, can be tuned
    s = s[:i] + "(" + s[i:]
    i += 2
    while i < len(s) - 2:
      i += 2
      if random.randint(0, 1): # 50% chance of closing paren, again can be tuned
        s = s[:i] + ")" + s[i:]
        break
    if i >= len(s) - 2: # safety closing paren
      s = s + ")"
  i += 2
```

This is not the cleanest code I've ever written, but it should be clear how the solution works (it just adds parens to every possible spot with 50% chance, then moves forward).  Let me know if you have any questions / want me to clean it up a bit